# How to read data from firebase and write it in textboxs javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, firebase

I am reading a lot of different data from my firebase database, currently, I have hard coded it. This works fine, however I have soo many lines of code that now when I want to alter my code it gets really confusing. Below I have pasted the current apporach I have taken.

```
var ref = new Firebase("URL");

// Data set 1
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();    
textbox1.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue1.age;
});

ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();   
textbox1.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue1.age;  
});

// Data set 2
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();    
textbox2.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue2.age; 
});

ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();   
textbox2.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue2.age;    
});
```

.....
 .....
 .....

```
// Data set 100
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();    
textbox100.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue100.age; 
});

ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();   
textbox100.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue100.age;   
});
```

Instead of the approach I have taken, is it possible to use a for loop or something like that to loop through each data because my structure for each textbox / keyword in firebase is more or less the same.

I am fairly new to javascript but from my knowledge of java, I believe it would be started of something like this;

```
var myTextbox = document.getElementById("mytextbox"); 
for (var i = 0; i < myTextbox.length; i++) {

}
```

Any help is welcomed, if my question is not clear please let me know.

EDITED:

```
Mydata:
textbox1 - value - age : "This is textbox 1, age:21"
textbox2 - value - age : "This is textbox 2, age:53"
textbox2 - value - age : "This is textbox 3, age:04"
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on firebase but here are some potential solutions you can try. For example, instead of writing a child_added and child_changed, you can use 'value'. ([Reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html))

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();    
textbox1.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue1.age;
});
```

But this is not a good solution for your problem as you want all the values retrieved at once. 
It seems your snapshot has all the values with attributes'getValuei' where i is from 1...n.
A better solution could be something like this..

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
var snapshot = snapshot.val();    
textbox1.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue1.age;
textbox2.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue2.age;
textbox3.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue3.age; //..and so on..
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but this only reads the data for first textbox I define in this case textbox1.innerHTML = snapshot.getvalue1.age; and also by using 'value' instead of data_added/data_changed it returns undefined.

Comment: you are most likely getting a list. You can try this to check - snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
  childsnapshot.val();
})